# Line integral using Stokes’ Theorem.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\vec{F}= 2y \hat{i}+ x^2 \hat{j} + xy \hat{k}$ and let C be the curve of intersection of the plane $x + y + z  = 1$ and the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Then find the value of $$\left|\oint \vec{F}.d\vec{r}\right|$$

My question is can I use Stokes’ Theorem in here? (Why or why not?) If yes, then which surface should I consider for evaluating the Normal vector? (That of the plane or that of the cylinder?). Also, kindly provide me with the solution of this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: You should use the part of the plane for your surface (just the part of the plane that is "cut out" by the cylinder). This is because the curve $C$ is the boundary of this surface.

Comment: Can you help me with the limits of this surface?

Comment: parameterize the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$ by $x = \cos(t)$ and $y = \sin(t)$. So you can parameterize the curve $C$ by $x = \cos(t)$, $y=\sin(t)$, and $z = 1 - \cos(t) - \sin(t)$, by using the equation of the plane.

Comment: Parameterizing this curve helped me reach the correct answer using line integral itself (thanks ^_^). But, isn't there a way to parameterize the surface so that I can get to the same result through surface integral?

Comment: The surface is simply the equation of the plane: $z = 1 - x - y$, and the bounds for the surface are $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\iint \nabla \times F\ dA = \oint f\cdot dr$

$\nabla \times F = (\frac{\partial}{\partial y} xy - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} x^2,\frac{\partial}{\partial z} 2y- \frac{\partial}{\partial x} xy,\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^2 -  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} 2y) = (x, -y, 2x-2)$

..... you can skip much of what follows, I am complicating things more than I need to ....

the normal to the surface is $(\frac {1}{\sqrt 3},\frac 1{\sqrt 3},\frac 1{\sqrt 3})$

$\iint \frac {3x - y - 2}{\sqrt 3} \ dS$

Parameterize that surface?

$u = \frac {x-y}{\sqrt 2}\\
v = \frac {x+y - 2z}{\sqrt 6} \\
w = \frac {x+y+z}{\sqrt 3}$

This coordinate transformation is orthonormal.

jacobian  $\ dx\ dy\ dz =  du\ dv\ dw$

In these coordinates $w = 0$

The semi-major axis of this elipse is at the point $(0,\sqrt {3},0)$
and the semi-minor axis is at $(1,0,0)$

or

$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} u + \frac {1}{\sqrt 6} v + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} w\\
y = -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} u + \frac {1}{\sqrt 6} v + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} w\\
z =  -\frac {2}{\sqrt 6} v + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} w$

$x^2 + y^2 = 1$ with $x+y+z = 0$ becomes $u^2 + \frac {v^2}3 = 1$ with $w= 0$

Putting it together we have

$\iint \frac {a_1 u + a_2 v  - 2}{\sqrt 3} \ du \ dv$

We don't need to work out what the linear coefficients of u,v are because whatever they are, over this ellipse:

$\iint a_1 u + a_2 v\ du\ dv = 0$

$-\frac 2{\sqrt 3} A$

$A$ is the area of the ellipse.  $A = \pi\sqrt 2$

The integral evaluates to $-2\pi$

.... Resume here, I don't have the heart do delete it .......

instead of the coordinate transformation, we can say:

$x = x\\y = z\\ z= -x-y\\dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\ dx\ dy$

$\iint (x, -y, 2x-2)\cdot (1,1,1)\ dx\ dy\\
\iint x -y+ 2x-2\ dx\ dy$

$\iint x -y+ 2x \ dx\ dy$ are odd functions evaluated over a region that is symmetric.

$\iint -2 \ dx\ dy = -2\pi$

How did this compare to calculating it directly?

$(x,y,z) = (\cos t, \sin t, 1 - \cos t - \sin t)
dr = (-\sin t, \cos t, 1 + \sin t - \cos t)$

$F\cdot dr = (2\sin t, \cos^2 t, \cos t\sin t)\cdot(-\sin t, \cos t, 1 + \sin t - \cos t)\\
-2\sin^2t + \cos^3 t + \cos t\sin t + \cos t\sin^2 t - \cos^2 t\sin t$

That is going to be a snap to integrate.  Most of those terms evaluate to 0

$\int_0^{2\pi} -2\sin^2t + \cos^3 t + \cos t\sin t + \cos t\sin^2 t - \cos^2 t\sin t \ dt\\
\int_0^{2\pi} -2\sin^2t\ dt\\
-2\pi$

Comment: Your efforts are much appreciated. Thank you. :) Just need to know how you decide the parameterization.

Comment: The first attempt was to find a vector normal to the plane and two vectors in the plane.  This drives the orthonormal coordinate transformation.  After dropping a factor ${\sqrt 2}$ (since found) and trying to fix it, I realized this was overkill.  $dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\ dx\ dy$ is a standard parameterization for surfaces where $z = f(x,y)$